# Navigation drawer not working while creating ActionBarDrawerToggle with Dagger2

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm trying to create instance of `ActionBarDrawerToggle` using `Module` of `dagger2` library.

```
    @Provides
    fun provideActionBarDrawerToggle():ActionBarDrawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(activity,activity.drawer_layout,activity.action_bar_top,
        R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
```

And I've injected the instance in my activity as well.

```
    @Inject 
    lateinit var toggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle
```

But when I click on `Drawer` Icon on the top left of my activity, `Navigation Drawer` do not opens.
If I slide left, then it shows `Navigation drawer`. 
Why instance provided by `dagger2` is not behaving as expected?

Comment: Where you added toggle listner on ActionBarDrawerToggle?

Comment: in the activity, drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)

Comment: Hey Sushant can you update the question with more code?

Comment: I'm afraid, I can't :)